# twitter bootstrap datepicker not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to run the example given in the [bootstrap datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/), but it is unable to render as it is shown in the website.I am running the site in an instance of google app engine. The input field of the datepicker seems to be shrunk. The code that i used is given below --

```
<html>
<head>  
    <title>
        Known Doctor Results | EasyPreScribe
    </title>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <table>

    {% for i in que %}
    <tr>
        <td name="docNamePass">{{i.doctorName}}</td>
        <td>{{i.clinicName}}</td>
        <td>{{i.clinicAdd}}</td>
        <td>{{i.contactNo}}</td>
        <td><form action="/bookTime">
        <div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
            <input class="span2" size="20" type="text" value="12-02-2012">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
            </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="docNamePass" value="{{i.doctorName}}">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        </td>
    </tr>   
    {% endfor %}
    </table>

    <a href= "{{ patLogOut }}" > Logout </a>
    <h1>{{ u }} </h1>
<script>
$(document).ready(function($) {
          $('#dp3').datepicker();
          });
</script>
</body>
    </html>
```

The result of this sample code [image]. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to put your inputs inside a `form` element to be correctly stylized...

Comment: I have a form element declared before the <div> of the datepicker Or are you talking about the form to be declared inside the <div> element's input?

Comment: That's true, sorry, misread...